# is there a formula/way to format a cell that is next to a cell with a specific format

Tags: excel, formatting

is there a formula/way to format a cell that is next to a cell with a specific format.
I have a worksheet with names and information on these persons. however i only want to colour the cell that is next to the column with the name of this person (which are already colored).

So is there a way (probably with conditional formatting i suppose) to color the cells that are next to another colored cell.

I know i can click each cell individually, but that takes hours of time with over a 1000 names that are not perfectly aligned under each other...

Comment: Yes i want to colour all the adjacent cells next to a cell that i already colored (i got these coloured because all the name cells contain 1st or 2nd, so i found all of these with the find all button and formatted those to orange.) and the cell next to those colored cells should turn green. So might 1st and 2nd possibly count as a rule for excel in any way?

Comment: Can you tell me step by step how to do so? I am not really that familiar with formulas and coding in excel...

Comment: yes i mean CF, a code that i can apply to all cells, that says adjecent cell to the left = orange ->so cell turns green

Comment: and with filter i will try now thank you!

Comment: yep they are spread all around (not in the same column) that is the problem.

Comment: could i use 1st and 2nd (that are always in a cell with a name) instead of the color with CF?

Comment: yes that has been provided, there is only 1st and 2nd in the cells with names. is there a standard formula where i can just type in 1st and second or something? if there is and you could help me out with that it would be VERY much appreciated!

Comment: If it would help i could send the file to you so you can get a better image of what i am trying to achieve, please let me know!

Comment: And remember, the cell next to the one with 1st or 2nd should be colored, the one with 1st and 2nd is already colored

Comment: I have found a way to select the cell that is next to a specific cell, while keeping the first selected cell selected, however i can only do this one cell at a time (ctrl + shift + right arrow key) if there is a way to do this for multiple loose cells at a time the problem would be fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

- Select the range to which you wish to apply the rules (covering both of them)
- In Format values where this formula is true:

  > =IFERROR(FIND("1st",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("2nd",A1),0)>0

  with orange fill.
- New Rule...:

  > =IFERROR(FIND("1st",XFD1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("2nd",XFD1),0)>0

  with green fill.
- Check the Applies to Range for both rules is appropriate - the first column should be the first in which a name may arise and the last one one to the right of the last in which a name might arise - this is assuming that by `next to` you mean immediately to the right of.

Test example:

[image: SO21936311 example]

With a blank column inserted as ColumnA, the formulae would be:

for orange: `=IFERROR(FIND("1st",B1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("2nd",B1),0)>0`
for green: `=IFERROR(FIND("1st",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("2nd",A1),0)>0`

and both with Applied to `=$B$1:$J$17` (or adjusted to suit).

Comment: It is giving a wrong formula notification on my end. But seeing it works for you it should be possible somehow. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: keeps saying that there is an error in the formula. Might there be a difference in . and , with your and mine version of excel (europe netherlands) it is however on english.

Comment: i copied your formula as well as re-typing it. but it doesn't accept it.

Comment: when i remove the "=" at the beginning of the formula it accepts it but no colors appear

Comment: i am using excel 2010

Comment: yes i did. and yes i believe you can't go without the = sign

Comment: could you send me the file which you send the screenshot from?

Comment: From there i might be able to input my information and use the already provided codes

Comment: it would really be helpfull